# Calling async methods within same class nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a class that has two methods and I am trying to call one method to another...

```js
class con {
  q(callback) {
    console.log('in method 2');
    this.q2(function(err, res) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      else {
        console.log(res)
      }
    })
  }

  q2(callback) {
    var result = 2 + 2;
    return callback(null, result)
  }
}
```

When I run the above code I get error:

> TypeError Cannot read property "q2" of undefined.....it gives error at line where this.q2.

Comment: Other than the typos, this works fine for me. How are you using it?

Comment: In q method I am ruining a query con.query(qry, function(err, result){ if(err){console.log(err} else { this.q2(function(........reat of code same as in question)

Comment: Make sure you define the methods as static or create and attach a variable to the class.

Comment: I do have module.exports=con;

Comment: Why you use `this.q2`? is that correct?

Comment: You need to create an *instance* of the class with `let someInstance = new con()` Then you can call the methods with `someInstance.q()` `this` doesn't make sense without an instance.

Comment: Mark I am calling methods with in same class so I don't think I need to create instance of same class? Instead I am using this.

Comment: You need to show us how you are calling `q()` - that's what's [important for `this` behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: @Bergi i am calling it as let c= new con(); c.q(function(are, res){ if(err){console.log(err)} else { console.log(res)} });

Comment: @J.Davidson I cannot reproduce your issue with that code.

Comment: like @Bergi that code also works fine for me.

Comment: Remove the "return" in "return callback(null, result)"